# What kind of parser Lua uses?

Tags: lua, programming-languages

I am trying to write my own programming language, and I use Lua source as a reference. 
I have several questions about it:

1. What kind of parser Lua use? Is it a Pratt parser?
2. ... and why it doesn't produce an AST? That's a job that parser does, isn't it?

Comment: 1. It is a recursive-descent parser; 2. No, not necessarily. Lua's parser is a so-called "shotgun parser" (which is usually discouraged if you want a clean separation): It emits bytecode right away rather than building an intermediate representation such as an AST - building such a linked structure is detrimental to performance and not needed for a simple language like Lua. The downside of this is that the parser can't be leveraged for other tools that might need an AST, such as documentation generation.